# Can't import file in python 3.8.8 with importlib

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to divide my code in multiple files, i tried 2 methods but both don't seem to work for me what am i doing wrong?

First of all this is how my file setup looks:

[image]

This is how my main.py looks

```html
import discord
import os
import importlib

client = discord.Client()

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
cm = '/bbc '

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

importlib.import_module('onMessage')

client.run('ACTUAL_TOKEN')
```

This is how my onMessage.py looks:

```html
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    # RANDOM MESSAGES
    if message.content.startswith(cm + 'hello'):
            if message.author.discriminator == '2622' or message.author.discriminator == '3377':
                await message.channel.send('Smoker')
            elif message.author.discriminator == '3072':
                await message.channel.send('Intellectual')
            else :
                await message.channel.send('Unknown?')

    if message.content.startswith('Foo bar'):
        if message.author.discriminator == '2622' or message.author.discriminator == '1266':
            await message.channel.send('Foo')
        else : 
            await message.channel.send('Bar')
```

i got the error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    importlib.import_module('onMessage')
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\marni\OneDrive\Documenten\Bureaublad\BBC\theBoysBotCorp\src\bbc_pkg\onMessage.py", line 1, in <module>
    @client.event
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

Then i tried

```html
import discord
import os
import onMessage

client = discord.Client()

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
cm = '/bbc '

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

    onMessage.on_message()
    
client.run('ACTUAL_TOKEN')
```

Got pretty much the same error but this time for onMessage when trying to do onMessage.on_message.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, I don't get any syntax errors. Please provide a [mcve]. If you are getting errors, post the entire error message, including the stack trace.

Comment: I've updated the question is this the information you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using cogs.

main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

client.load_extension('cogs.onmessage')

client.run('token')
```

cogs/onmessage.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

cm = '/bbc '

class Whatever(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client  
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.client.user:
            return
        # RANDOM MESSAGES
        if message.content.startswith(cm + 'hello'):
                if message.author.discriminator == '2622' or message.author.discriminator == '3377':
                    await message.channel.send('Smoker')
                elif message.author.discriminator == '3072':
                    await message.channel.send('Intellectual')
                else :
                    await message.channel.send('Unknown?')

        if message.content.startswith('Foo bar'):
            if message.author.discriminator == '2622' or message.author.discriminator == '1266':
                await message.channel.send('Foo')
            else : 
                await message.channel.send('Bar')

            
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Whatever(client))
```

---

### **References:**

- [Cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html)

Comment: Error:

File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
   client.load_extension('cogs.onmessage')
  File "C:\Users\marni\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 674, in load_extension
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\util.py", line 94, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cogs'

Comment: create a folder called cogs and place onmessage.py there

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marni\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: Also I noticed that `cm = '/bbc '` is in main.py and not in onmessage.py

Comment: TypeError: on_message() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

at the end, didn't realise that it didn't fit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231617/discussion-between-marnix-elling-and-rashid).